# check is String vowel or consonant using java?

Tags: java

How do I check whether a String begins with a vowel or a consonant sound? For instance, **University** begins with a consonant sound; **Hour** begins with a vowel sound.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    char ch;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a word : ");
    ch = scan.next().charAt(0);

    if(ch=='a' || ch=='A' || ch=='e' || ch=='E' ||
    ch=='i' || ch=='I' || ch=='o' || ch=='O' ||
    ch=='u' || ch=='U')
    {
        System.out.print("This is a Vowel");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print("This is not a Vowel");
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have a question?

Comment: your code doesn´t even remotly close reflect what you ask. Despite that defining `University` as constant and `Hour` as vowel doesn´t really make sense for me

Comment: @asheeshpatel well with that attitide you wont ever get a promising answer. As i already said and ScaryWombat wanted to say aswell. You didn´t ask a specific question. Your main question is completly unrelated to programming. You asked how you can identify a word as a vowel. Additionally your code still doesn´t reflect what you asked as you just check how the `String` does start.

Comment: @KevinEsche, yeah you are right i didn't asked specific question but you can understand the problem i just want to check String on the basis of Article... Univirsity so A Univirsity, a Uniform , an umbrela, an Hour... Got it?

Comment: @asheeshpatel yeah now i got it i guess, but it was also confusing i´d say because both, `University` and `hour` should start with an `an`. I think there is no easy way to do it, as there are silent letter as in `hour`. Basicly you´ve to transfer the english grammar rules to your code which might be to broad for a `SO` question.

Comment: @asheeshpatel which is correct `You have a Horrible attitude` or `You have an Horrible attitude`

Comment: @ScaryWombat i will go for A Horrible but now i wanna check in java program then how you do this?

Comment: Clarified problem statement in light of later comment from OP.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this reasonably simply by examining the first letter.  Rather, you need to refer to an on-line dictionary and use the first phoneme of the pronunciation.  You've already coded the simple implementation: check the first letter.  However, as your counterexamples show, this is not enough.

If this is a homework assignment, please contact your instructor for access to the pronunciation file.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static int vovelsCount(String str) {
    return str.replaceAll("[^aeiou]","").length();
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, 
**[including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) 
really helps to improve the quality of your post**. Remember that you are 
answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might 
not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd 
your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both 
the code and the explanations!

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

/**
  * Java Program to count vowels in a String. It accept a String 
    from command promptand count how many vowels it contains. To revise, 
    5 letters a, e, i, o and u are known as 
    vowels in English.
  */

```
public class VowelCounter {

 public static void main(String args[]) {
      System.out.println("Please enter some text");
      Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);                  

  String input = reader.nextLine();
      char[] letters = input.toCharArray();

  int count = 0;

  for (char c : letters) {
       switch (c) {
          case 'a':
              case 'e':
              case 'i':
              case 'o':
              case 'u':
                  count++;
      break;
      default:
              // no count increment
      }

   }
        System.out.println("Number of vowels in String [" + input + "] is : " + count);
 }

}
```